# A sufficient condition on a real smooth function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, functions

Let $f : [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function. 
I would like to find a sufficient condition on $f$ in order to have that
$$
\liminf_{t\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^t \Big(\frac{t - s}{s} \Big)^2 f' '(s) \, ds \le 0.
$$

Of course I could assume $f' ' \le 0$, but I'm looking for a weaker assumption that could in principle allow $f' ' $ to be positive at some points.

Thank you!!

**Edit**: It would be ok also to assume that there exists a $t_0 > 0 $ such that $f' '(t) \le 0$ for every $t \ge t_0$. It is more important to me to allow the existence of points where $f' '$ is possibly nonpositive in a closed interval. While I can be more rigid on the behaviour of $\varphi$ at infinity.